# Php - Is the security level of crypt('password', '$2a$12$' . $salt) equal to password_hash() method

Tags: php, hash, passwords, bcrypt, crypt

The question my seem nerd but I'm a newbie to those PHP password encryption libraries and methods.

I found a lot of posts about use `bcrypt` for highest level of secure password hashing.

I found out that in **PHP 5.5**, we can use `password_hash()` function to create a `bcrypt` password. But most of hosting web servers still don't support **PHP 5.5**. It is really awkward.

I also found out another commonly use function `crypt()` which support six hashing algorithms. It is fortunate that this function can also produce `bcrypt` hashed password by providing proper **format string** such as `$2a$12$`. Again official php docs says that it is supported in PHP 5. Therefore I decided to use this one for my project.

I just want to know that the security level of this crypt() function (with `$2a$12$`) is equal to `password_hash()` function of PHP 5.5.

I also found out that `password_hash()` [compatible library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) for lower version of PHP. Is this library provide other advantages over `crypt()` function?

Please, share your any suggestions. I'm really ambiguous now. Thanks in advance.

Comment: All of your questions are answered there. The title is not the same, but the answer with 540 upvotes addresses your queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$2a$` hashes are not secure, see [this](http://www.php.net/security/crypt_blowfish.php) page for details. PHP 5.3.7 and above uses `$2y$`. `crypt` can generate secure hashes, but you need to provide a salt manually. If you generate a weak salt, then the hash won't be secure enough.

Because of this, I suggest to use `password_compat`. It was developed by Anthony Ferrara who implemented the `password_hash` functions into PHP 5.5. It provides an easy and secure way to hash and compare passwords.

Comment: Thanks for giving your suggestion. After I read my apparently duplicated question, I've decided to use password_compat.